# Changing engine mode of aurora cluster from provisioned to serverless

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora, aws-aurora-serverless

We have a Aurora Mysql provisioned serverless v2 cluster running with 8.0.mysql_aurora.3.04.0.
We want it to convert to Serverless v1.
I got to know that Serverless v1 requires engine mode as "Serverless"
But I don't see any option to change engine mode from Provisioned to Serverless v1.
Just wanted to confirm if someone already modified existing provisioned cluster to serverless.
Thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert Serverless v1 to provisioned [1], but not the other way around. A workaround would be to take a snapshot of your database and restore it to a Serverless v1 cluster, but in your case, this wouldn't work because Serverless v1 does not support MySQL 8 [2].

[1] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.modifying.html#aurora-serverless.modifying.convert
[2] https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/aurora-serverless.relnotes.html

Comment: So in my case there is no option other than creating new serverless v1 and migrating data from v2 to v1 ?

Comment: You may not even be able to migrate your data to v1, because v1 does not support MySQL 8.0, only 5.7.